# parsing xml to skip tags

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have the following stylesheet to skip the tags XYZ_1, XYZ_2.

- How do i get it to work for XYZ_*
- Also, in the output the tags that are skipped have empty lines, how do i suppress them.

Thanks in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="html" indent="no" encoding="utf-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

<xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
                <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="XYZ_1" />
<xsl:template match="XYZ_2" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is the sample XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tags>
    <tag>
        <tag1>TagName1</tag1>
        <XYZ_1>
            <name>1.pdf</name>
        </XYZ_1>
        <XYZ_2>
            <c_name>chart1.gif</c_name>
        </XYZ_2>
    </tag>
</tags>
```

the output comes out to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tags>
    <tag>
        <tag1>TagName1</tag1>





    </tag>
</tags>
```

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, short and simple solution to your *both* problems. This solution uses the most fundamental and powerful XSLT design pattern -- overriding the identity rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(), 'XYZ_')]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tags>
    <tag>
        <tag1>TagName1</tag1>
        <XYZ_1>
            <name>1.pdf</name>
        </XYZ_1>
        <XYZ_2>
            <c_name>chart1.gif</c_name>
        </XYZ_2>
    </tag>
</tags>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<tags>
   <tag>
      <tag1>TagName1</tag1>
   </tag>
</tags>
```

**Explanation**:

1. **The identity rule (unless overriden) copies every node** as-is
2. **The only overriding template is matching elements whose `name()` `starts-with()` "XYZ_"** and this template has empty body -- this effectively deletes any matched element from the output.
3. **The `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` directive** instructs the XSLT processor to parse the XML document ignoring any whitespace-only text node in the document. Thus no whitespace-only node are seen by the transformation hence no such nodes are copied to the output. This eliminates the unwanted whitespace, reported as a second problem.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you would use starts-with, as follows:

```
<xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(), 'XYZ_')]">
```

This should apply the template to any element that starts with the specified four characters.

Not sure from the information provided about the second part of your question. Could you post a sample of the file being parsed?

Comment: just edit the question to reflect the xml file being parsed and the output produced